# How does the 4th argument of scandir() work?

Tags: c, function, scandir

The definition of [`scandir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir) looks like this:

```
int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
   int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
   int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

What is `compar`? What difference does it make what callback I pass there? The man page doesn't seem to say anything. Is it safe to pass NULL there? Can someone explain to me the purpose and usage of the 4th argument? I already did my research, and didn't find any useful information so, well, here I am.

Comment: Which man page do you have? Mine says “… sorted using qsort(3) with the comparison function compar()…”. You can probably find it online.

Comment: @Ry- The link in the question is the man page I am using for reference.

Comment: It says the same thing in your link. Ctrl+F compar

Comment: You need to read the [`qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) man page as well because `scandir` passes `compar` straight thru to `qsort`. That is, the `compar` function determines the order of the displayed results.

Comment: @0People The page you linked says "*The alphasort() and versionsort() functions can be used as the comparison function compar().*" and it also gives a usage example.

Comment: The man page you linked to says “Entries for which filter() returns nonzero are stored in strings allocated via malloc(3), _sorted using qsort(3) with the comparison function compar()_, and ...” (emphasis mine) What else would you like to know about it?

Comment: @kaylum I guess I understand it now, but is it safe to pass NULL to `compar`?

Comment: No, if you do that it will crash.

Comment: @zwol When I tried it it worked, so are you saying it's UB and I just got lucky?

Comment: The man page and posix specification are silent on that point. So I would say it is implementation dependent. I would not rely on it.

Comment: @kaylum I wouldn't rely on _what_ again, passing in NULL?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on it working if `NULL` is passed as it would depend on the libc implementation being used.

Comment: ISO C section 7.1.4p1 applies to qsort, and transitively to scandir: "If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: I'm actually very surprised to hear that it didn't crash. The only explanation I can think of is that maybe the test directory was empty and so qsort had nothing to do.

Comment: @zwol: The first two implementations I checked, glibc and openbsd, test the value of `compar` and if it's NULL they simply skip the sort.  This behavior is certainly not required by POSIX but it seems like a useful extension, and perhaps one that OP's system provides as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It determines the order in which the items are listed, in a similar manner to [`qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort). Passing NULL is undefined behavior. Thanks for the comments.